# Separate php.ini for different virtual hosts

Tags: apache, php

Is there a way to have separate php.ini files for different virtual hosts in apache?

I prefer not to use any mods

Comment: There is the `php_flag` option in Apache; other than that, not sure. But your question is probably better suited for Serverfault; the moderators here will hopefully move your question there. You don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FAST CGI is apparently the answer to this, I did a lot of digging, apache by itself doesn't seem to be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on howtoforge; http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-ubuntu-8.10

I thinkit uses a mod however.