# Php ini settings not working as set

Tags: php

I got these php.ini settings on the web application folder.

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = "UTF-8";
memory_limit = 64M;
max_execution_time = 3600;
upload_max_filesize = 10M;
sql.safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
allow_url_fopen = Off;
session.auto_start = Off;
session.use_only_cookies = On;
session.use_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.cookie_httponly = On;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600;
session.cookie_secure =On;
session.entropy_file = "/dev/urandom";
```

To check whether these settings are enforced, I saved these codes to a file checksettings.php

```
<?php

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    echo "Magic quotes are enabled";
else
    echo "Magic quotes are disabled";

echo '<br>';
echo 'Register Globals = ' . ini_get('register_globals');
echo '<br>';
echo 'Default Charset = ' . ini_get('default_charset');
echo '<br>';
echo 'Memory Limt = ' . ini_get('memory_limit');
echo '<br>';
echo 'Max Execution Time = ' . ini_get('max_execution_time');
echo '<br>';
echo 'Upload Max File Size = ' . ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
echo '<br>';
echo 'Sql Safe Mode = ' . ini_get('sql.safe_mode');
echo '<br>';
echo 'MySQL connect Timeout = ' . ini_get('mysql.connect_timeout');
echo '<br>';
echo 'Allow url fOpen = ' . ini_get('allow_url_fopen');
echo '<br>';
```

On loading the checksettings.php on my web browser I get these output

```
Magic quotes are disabled
Magic Quotes =
Register Globals =
Default Charset = UTF-8
Memory Limt = 128M
Max Execution Time = 30
Upload Max File Size = 2M
Sql Safe Mode =
MySQL connect Timeout =
Allow url fOpen = 1
```

Now, as far as I understand, the blanks (Register Globals = , Sql Safe Mode = etc.) are due to (I believe) syntax error (which I will look into) but a few values are not as I set them to be.

The Memory Limit which was set to 64M is 128M, Max Execution time which was set to 3600 is 30s, Upload Max File Size which is set to 10M is 2M and Allow url fopen which was set 0 or Off is 1/on.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Restarted apache/php handler after editing php.ini ?

Comment: You want me to restart my xamp server?

Comment: I already did that and have the same results

Comment: php.ini in your web root ? Are you sure this is even overridden ? This is not a default behavior

Comment: put `phpinfo()` Check `loaded_config` and make sure you are editing right ini file.

Comment: @Harikrishnan, okay, I get this. I need to edit the C:\xampp\php\php.ini. But is there a way to override the settings without actually having to touch the php.ini on C:\xampp\php.?

Comment: Try adding your changes in your vhost like this is done here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309620/how-do-i-create-custom-php-ini-files-for-each-virtual-host

Answer (score 0):

First, you need be sure that you're editing the right php.ini file: you can check int with a `phpinfo()` file.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Then, make alterations on the right php.ini file and then restart the webserver.

I hope this helps.